# Is there way to see active queries/requests running in Apache Cassandra?

Tags: cassandra, python-requests, monitor

This is the question. Not metrics like latency, active threads, etc. Pure and plain queries. Is this possible? How? Thanks.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Not currently no, just the number of requests from native transport requests in `nodetool tpstats`

**Update**: After [CASSANDRA-15241](https://issues.apache.org/jira/browse/CASSANDRA-15241) you can query a virtual table like:

```
cqlsh> select * from system_views.queries;

 thread_id    | duration_micros | task
--------------+-----------------+-------------------------------------
 ReadStage-10 |           16535 | SELECT * FROM basic.wide1 LIMIT 5000
 ReadStage-13 |           16535 | SELECT * FROM basic.wide1 LIMIT 5000
 ReadStage-14 |           16535 | SELECT * FROM basic.wide1 LIMIT 5000
```

Comment: Wow thanks for quick answer. Do you know if this feature is requested in Cassandra?

Comment: it would be a good idea to create a new jira, people can always mark it duplicate.

Comment: `nodetool profileload` will provide closer to this in 4.0. 3.x has `nodetool toppartitions` to at least see partitions being written to and read from.